# How do you use USB audio interface on Ubuntu to begin recording music? Using Focusrite Scarlett Solo device

Tags: usb, sound, interface

I installed Ubuntu but cannot find anywhere on the system, a link to the USB audio interface device. Where would it possibly be? How do I find it and begin to use it to create my own music recordings?

Comment: Install Audacity and see if you can select it as an input.

Answer (score 1):

try typing "lsusb" in command-line to see if Linux detected the USB audio interface.

If its there in the list you can configure input and output of the device in the sound TAB of the Ubuntu settings application.